# Difference between VB .NET web application and C# .NET web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I followed the instructions as in the [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316726)  to create a website that may add two numbers together. The original app is created in VB, which works perfectly fine. Then I convert VB to C# but the website won't show the sum of the two inputs. The following is my code and I don't see a difference except that C# app has an extra Page_Load method. Does `Page_Load` method have anything to do with the outcomes? Please help :)

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int intTotal;
            int intFirstNumber;
            int intSecondNumber;

            // Get the values from the input boxes.
            intFirstNumber = Convert.ToInt32(txtFirstNumber.Text);
            intSecondNumber = Convert.ToInt32(txtSecondNumber.Text);

            // Get the total and display it.
            intTotal = intFirstNumber + intSecondNumber;
            txtSum.Text = Convert.ToString(intTotal);
        }

        protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the relevant aspx.  There is a good chance your button has `Button1_Click1` assigned to it's OnClick event not the one with the code that actually does the work.

Comment: You have created two button click, Can you make sure you are calling the correct button1_click function.

Comment: Also note that the article you refer to was last revised  06/19/2012 and applies to .net 1.0 and 1.1, we are now up to .net 4.5.1 .As such it is quite old.

Comment: remove second Button1_Click1

Comment: Very good chance is, you are not calling correct event.. show your view code pls

Comment: The difference between VB web application and C# web application is that one is written in VB and another is in C#.

Comment: @AmneshGoel Thank you, you are right about not calling the correct event thing. I remove Button1_Click method and it works fine.

Comment: @JonP Oh, I didn't realize that article was old. Thank you for your remainder. I am totally new to .net, hopefully I will catch up soon.

Comment: @Amanda.J Thanks, I have posted that as an answer to this question. You  may accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very good chance is, you are not calling correct event... you can check at your view level for the right event.. and accordingly make the changes at server side.